# How do I receive parameters from jsp from js?

Tags: javascript, java, html, post, parameters

I am looking for a way to receive parameters sent by `.JS` as `.JSP`.

The file receiving the parameter is `JSP`, but it is the script that must be used.

**sendParameter.jsp**

```
<form name="frm" action="adminGNB.jsp" method="POST" >
    <div class="form-line">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="admin_id" id="admin_id" onkeyup="enterkey()">
    </div>
    <div class="form-line">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="admin_password" id="admin_password" onkeyup="enterkey()">
    </div>
    <div class="btn-wrap">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="login" onClick="loginbutton()">login</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**receive Parameter.jsp**

```
<%
  request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
  String name = (String)request.getSession().getAttribute("admin_id");
  System.out.println("admin_id :" + name);
%>

<script>
$(function(){

    changeYourPassword();
    latestNoticeCheck();
});
....
</script>
```

I'm using `Java` to receive `parameters` sent by `JSP`, as you can see by the code. But where I have to use the `parameters` in `<script>`. How can I get the parameters?

I don't use the `GET` method.

`getParameter("admin_id")` is don't work

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try just use ${admin_id}  or %=admin_id% ?

Comment: @toootooo I don't understand what you mean. Please attach the example code to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code should be working .....

```
<script>
$(function(){
    var myVar = '<%= request.getSession().getAttribute("admin_id") %>';
    changeYourPassword();
    latestNoticeCheck();
});
....
</script>
```

Comment: But there's a problem. Why can't you have a password? request.getSession().getAttribute("admin_password") is null

Comment: i did not understand your question

Comment: The value 'admin_id' can be obtained, but the 'admin_password' value is null.